# Calculate average of a promise called every x seconds during y seconds

Tags: javascript, typescript

Hi I need to calculate the average of a promise called every 1 second during 3 seconds

Without success I have tried this:

```
     return new Promise(resolve=>{
       var c = { x : 0 , y : 0};
       var list = [1,2,3];
       const task = async () => {
         for (const item of list) {
           await new Promise(r => setTimeout(getGeoLoc, 1000));
           console.log('Yello, D\'oh');
      }
      let l = list.length
      c.x = c.x / l;
      c.y = c.y /l;
    }
    return resolve(c)
    function getGeoLoc(){
      return this.coords.then(resp=>{
         c.x = c.x + resp.x;
         c.y = c.y + resp.y
         return
    })}
})
```

Comment: You never call `task`. Your whole code can be reduced to `return new Promise(resolve => { resolve({ x: 0, y: 0 }); });` with equivalent behavior.

Comment: Is not clear what you are trying to measure here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code, here's something that should help you compute the average coordinates that you seem to want to find:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAdwIYyogFAEwKYA2qAngLIDOAXImCALYBGeATgJTUAKzcdM5eAHgBucGDgB8iAN4BYAFCJEzPFBDMkYPMkRcefPFmXlEAXkn8oAFRh08cEFEN5yAGkT4iZcq1YBueQC+8vKgkLAIiADmKgBKqGA4PACSYJhYvEgmiAAMbnSoAB6miACM7DT0TMzS8orKquqIpKhQABYAdMAEcHDMWM1t7czxiXRYrIgAVNj5RQDUpYgAtIgZPogLGf5yQXLyUMQADniIAMI9zDjGWTF4EL04AgDkBU+IAD6IT8RPbrSMLHE23kAHoQYg2nxEFDUKs4BAANaIYC9FCtFp4IQsRAAIkh5Ha9we5Bx0PI8lQ5GIkGR4Gg8CQ0Sg52J2HKul4-AELMu5EksgUiHuYHImCKWSZcQSyVSWFypWy2T8tSFCFFiGIxUlIxljnlJUVysF9TUSCkBTcxAC212ITp4SQqCEkR5V1uOBAEGxWBVTsi1FdrhV5stAQDFyuLhVMASeAK1H+VSjgqkBDwYEibTDZwj5AA2gBdZPlQM1QV+9rzLIFbaKCuauZZYjAwUwYDYGP4cUmLJpjNtZalCYCxR152VxAg3vpzOtWuj+uT6f9ucq23GlSmxB+m3BOSU6kQWlhBmrdBIcZlxTC9VE3kc-RUHTcTmCQPiQvFQstxQo6pYNNMBgYpsl8aFEAERAAGYwOAxshyvBc0AwFB0EcA1DXna9cwffgCUOEByFaLAmUDcYjUUddsJFTAnRYVBolLLIsFQZDMFwvB2lQAgCCwO8rg47xWCGPAPS9FjnUDd1PRYI0VRvOA03abpIgk+jGNzI113yGNxm2IA)

```ts
function wait (delayMs: number): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, delayMs));
}

function getRandomInt (min = 0, max = 1): number {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max + 1 - min)) + min;
}

type Coords = Record<'x' | 'y', number>;

// this is a mock for whatever "this.coords" is
async function getCoords (): Promise<Coords> {
  const x = getRandomInt(0, 100);
  const y = getRandomInt(0, 100);
  return {x, y};
}

function avgCoordsReducer (
  avg: Coords,
  {x, y}: Coords,
  index: number,
  {length}: Coords[],
): Coords {
  avg.x += x;
  avg.y += y;

  if (index === length - 1) {
    avg.x /= length;
    avg.y /= length;
  }

  return avg;
}

async function main () {
  const coordsPromises: Promise<Coords>[] = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
    await wait(1000);
    coordsPromises.push(getCoords());
  }

  const averageCoords = (await Promise.all(coordsPromises)).reduce(avgCoordsReducer);

  console.log(averageCoords);
}

main();
```